# How is possible to apply toUpperCase() on an empty String in Java?

Tags: java, string, language-concepts

I've thought that if I run this

```
System.out.println("toUpperCase() on empty String:"+ "".toUpperCase());
```

and it returns an empty String. How is that possible? toUpperCase() should fail in this case isn't it? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why should it fail? It converts any character of the input String to upper case. In your example, "any character" is equivalent to 0 characters.

The Javadoc doesn't say that it should fail for an empty String, which
means it shouldn't fail :

> Converts all of the characters in this String to upper case using the
>   rules of the default locale. This method is equivalent to
>   toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()).
>
> **Note:** This method is locale sensitive, and may produce unexpected
>   results if used for strings that are intended to be interpreted locale
>   independently. Examples are programming language identifiers, protocol
>   keys, and HTML tags. For instance, "title".toUpperCase() in a Turkish
>   locale returns "T\u0130TLE", where '\u0130' is the LATIN CAPITAL
>   LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE character. To obtain correct results for
>   locale insensitive strings, use toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH).
>
> **Returns:** the String, converted to uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

An empty string is not null, therefore, you can invoke all String methods on it.